# Build an iPhone app created with React Native

Tags: iphone, compilation

Is a Mac mandatory to build an iPhone app written in React Native?

If no, what are alternative ways? (like a container?!)

If yes, is there a backward compatibility matrix how old can a Mac be to support building of apps targeted to more recent iPhone devices?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that Apple currently uses the x86-64 hardware platform, it's quite an [easy exercise](https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-sierra-vmware-windows/) to install MacOS with VMWare and thus also use XCode to compile iOS apps.